# rocketchip emualtor c++ models

Tags: riscv, chisel

Rocketship emulator generates some c++ models/emulators in generated-src folder. Can anyone elaborate what are they? More description would be really helpful 
I am learning about how chisel generated emulator are helpful for small riscv even without rocketship generator

Comment: how can I use the ventilator in these case? Thanks

Comment: I sense translation issues. it would be good to mark up propietary names to differ them from common engllish words

Comment: small riscv is based on riscV isa which use gcc to get out binary of your program

Comment: i have created the uart through which i can pass my data into core.